# Cannot be cast to type :naive_datetime in query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have query:

```
 PhoenixApp.one(from r in PhoenixApp.Reply,
              where: r.inserted_at > ^datatime,
              select: count(r.id))
```

This query fails with error: `value '#Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-04 20:11:21>' in 'where' cannot be cast to type :naive_datetime in query:`

But when convert datatime using `type(^datatime, Ecto.DateTime)` it's works.

**Question**: Whay it's happend, looks like datatime initially have `DateTime` type?

Using new Ecto 2.1.2

Comment: How are you setting the value of `datatime`? Looks like it's a charlist and not a date? (Also, you're missing a comma after `datatime` in the code you posted.)

Comment: datatime is a `timestamp without time zone` field from another table and selected by another query. `IO.Inspect` of `datatime` is `#Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-04 20:11:21>` Comma is my fault, fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like Ecto does not support casting from the deprecated `Ecto.DateTime` to the new Elixir `NaiveDateTime` struct, which you're using when you use `:naive_datetime` in Ecto 2.1+:

```
iex(1)> dt = Ecto.DateTime.utc
#Ecto.DateTime<2017-01-08 12:11:59>
iex(2)> Ecto.Type.cast :naive_datetime, dt
:error
```

The recommended way in Ecto 2.1 is to stop using deprecated `Ecto.DateTime` struct and use Elixir's new `NaiveDateTime` (or `DateTime`) everywhere. If you still want to explicitly convert between them, you can do `|> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl |> NaiveDateTime.from_erl!` and use that value in your query:

```
iex(1)> dt = Ecto.DateTime.utc
#Ecto.DateTime<2017-01-08 12:13:50>
iex(2)> dt |> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl |> NaiveDateTime.from_erl!
~N[2017-01-08 12:13:50]
```

If you're getting the old structs from Ecto queries, you probably have the old types defined for them in your schemas, which you should change from `field :foo, Ecto.DateTime` to `field :foo, NaiveDateTime` (or `field :foo, DateTime`).

See also: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.1/CHANGELOG.md#integration-with-elixir-13-calendar-types.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! I got it, the problem which confused me it timestamps() function in schema. Probably it's a bug in Ecto, still adding `Ecto.DateTime` into chemas?

Comment: Just `timestamps()` in `schema` seems to be adding `NaiveDateTime` for me in Ecto 2.1.2. Are you sure it's using `Ecto.DateTime` automatically for you?

Comment: Thanks, it's works. Type  `Ecto.DateTime` was in another field

Comment: In my case I had to change Ecto.DateTime to use DateTime instead